# How to Apply CSS to input tag values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a input tag with this css.

```
#myInput {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #95B8E7;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

I wanted my Input field value should be `underline` and ';' at the end. How should I write CSS for that.

Here is I am setting my input Value.

```
function selectItem(input, value) {
        input.value += " "+value+";";

    }
```

Comment: `text-decoration: underline`

Comment: This is partially correct but how to apply in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-decoration: underline;` to your CSS, and just call your function by selecting your HTML element, like so: `selectItem(document.getElementById('myInput'),'foo')`.

Working Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tacj0eeq/2/